# php сравнение строки со списком строк

Tags: php, сравнение

У меня есть такой список в txt (site.com/1.txt) файле на сайте:

```
40.78.41.141
40.78.99.1
40.79.79.194
40.84.57.100
40.85.143.7
40.91.206.50
40.114.226.241
```

Я хочу сравнить IP пользователя со списком и если список содержит IP - выполнить действие 1, а если не содержит - выполнить действие 2

Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `file` позволит вам прочитать содержимое файла в массив, а функция `in_array` определит содержит ли массив заданное значение, в данном случае значение это элемент `REMOTE_ADDR` глобального массива `$_SERVER`, который содержит IP-адрес пользователя.

```
$lines = file('путь или URL к файлу', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $lines)){
    // действие 1
}else{
    // действие 2
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Что-то не срабатывает. Все время происходит "// действие 2" вне зависимости есть IP в базе или нет

Comment: print_r($lines); выдает:

`Array ( [0] => [1] => 1.0.136.30 [2] => 1.0.136.29 ...`
Не знаю почему, но мне кажется нужно перебирать в цикле

Comment: Если `$ip = 1;`, получаем "действие 1" при такой проверке `in_array($ip, $lines)`

Comment: Попробуйте включить строгую проверку в in_array, для этого передайте true третьим параметром.
if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $lines,true)){ ... }else{ ... }
Если не поможет попробуйте для поиска айпи использовать функцию array_search
if(false !== array_search($ip,$lines)){ ... }else{ ... }

Comment: и в вызов file надо добавить вторым параметром FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES